# Receiving AttributeError: __exit__ even when WITH object has EXIT defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm receiving an error of `AttributeError: __exit__` in the code below after finishing the `with` section. The Element object has is being returned in the `with` and it has `__exit__` defined, so I'm baffled.

```
class Builder:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Builder init fires")

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return Element(name, self)

class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, builder):
        self.name = name
        self.builder = builder
        print("Element init fires for name of", self.name)
    def __call__(*args, **kargs):
        print("CALL fires, now with attributes listed:")
        for attr, value in sorted(kargs.items()):
            print(' %s=>%s' % (attr, value))

    def __enter__(self):  
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback): 
        pass

aa = Builder()        
with aa.feed(xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'):
    print("INSIDE THE WITH")
```

Comment: When I run the code, I get an AttributeError for `__enter__`, because your `__call_` returns None.

Comment: It appears that under python 3.5.2 it receives an `AttributeError` for `__exit__` but under python 3.6.1 its for `__enter__`. I see you're correct that `__call__()` determines what is being returned by the `with` and it needs to have `return self`. Thanks.

Comment: Similar to missing parameters, omitting params  and () completely will throw the same exception.  For example: `with aa.feed:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of expression after `with` keyword must be a valid context manager. That means the **value** of the expresion must have attributes **`__enter__`** and **`__exit__`** and these must accept parameters described in docs [With Statement Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). You can easily verify that the part `aa.feed` would be acceptable, but the value of whole expression is `None` and it has no necessary attribute. A difference between Python 3.5 and 3.6 is that one fails on missing `__exit__` and the latter on missing `__enter__`. Nothing unexpected.

You also forgot `self` in the line `def __call__(self, *args, **kargs):` that would be a problem if you will use args and it is a pythonic pattern also with unused args.